# Cant start mongo DB in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
 mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-10-24 13:22:56 IST; 11s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 3811 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 3811 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 58ms

Oct 24 13:22:56 Nithyanandha systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Oct 24 13:22:56 Nithyanandha mongod[3811]: {"t":{"$date":"2022-10-24T07:52:56.619Z"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":205>
Oct 24 13:22:56 Nithyanandha systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 24 13:22:56 Nithyanandha systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

i am new to Mongodb i tried to install mongodb in ubuntu
at first it runs after some days it doest work
Mongodb Does't start it gives more error

Comment: Check your logfile, typically at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: no dir called mongodb in `/var/log`

Comment: Then check `systemLog.path` in `/etc/mongod.conf` at which folder the logs are written.

Comment: ``` # mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

```

Comment: So maybe the error is, because `/var/log/mongodb/` does not exist.

Comment: Or try to start it manually: `/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf --logpath /proc/$$/fd/0`

Comment: do i have to copy paste that cmd

Comment: while i  tried to delete mongodb, i found that there is no file in `/var/lib/mongodb`

Comment: You must create folder `/var/lib/mongodb` and mongod user must have write permissions to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249015/discussion-between-gowtham-v-and-wernfried-domscheit).

Comment: Thank you for your response i reinstalled the mongodb